# How to use timer in c# windows form to move elevator up and down only when button is pressed?

Tags: c#, animation, timer

I have been trying move elevator up and down in c# using timer when button is pressed but somehow I failed in that task. Below is the code I was trying use to make it happen.Would you please help me out?

```
private void timer_elevator_go_down_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (elevator.Top <= y_ff)
    {
        elevator.Top += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        timer_elevator_go_down.Enabled = false;

        btn_down.Enabled = true;

        btn_G.Enabled = true;

        btn_up.BackColor = Color.Red;

        btn_1.BackColor = Color.Red;


        arrived_G = true;

        elevator.Image = global::PLift_Control.Properties.Resources.elevator;
    }
}
```

Here following variables I declared.

```
public partial class ElevatorControl : Form
{
    int y_gf = 100;

    int y_ff = 347;

    bool go_up = false;

    bool go_down = false;

    bool arrived_G = false;

    bool arrived_1 = false;
```

Comment: Hi, please post a complete, minimal example that people could compile to see where the problem might be, and include a description of the actual problem (dysfunction, malfunction, exception, which?, ...)

Comment: "*but somehow I failed in that task*" - that's not really helpful. What were you expecting to see and what did really happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is that you're trying to change the location using the wrong method. Here's how you change the location:

```
elevator.Location = new Point(elevator.Location.X, elevator.Location.Y + 1);
// +1 being whatever amount you would like to increase/decrease it by
```